# How to filter result after a specific value

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_profile_data.*
FROM relation_table,user_profile_data
WHERE user_profile_data.ref_user_id=relation_table.user2
and relation_table.type = 1
AND relation_table.user1 = 184
ORDER BY user_profile_data.full_name ASC
```

I have this query which produces result table shown here:-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340f0/1

```
FULL_NAME   LOCATION    REF_USER_ID
Fake        IN          181
Fake gupta  IN          185
Fake kumar  IN          182
Fake sharma IN          183
Fakeme  IN              180
Manish Kumawat US       192
```

now i want to modify my query so as to get results which are after 'Fake Kumar' having id=182 like this:-

```
FULL_NAME   LOCATION    REF_USER_ID

Fake sharma IN          183
Fakeme  IN              180
Manish Kumawat US       192
```

i cannot use `user_profile_data.full_name>'Fake Kumar'` because of some security issues what I can use is id but if I use `user_profile_data.ref_user_id>182` i get results like:-

```
FULL_NAME   LOCATION    REF_USER_ID

Fake gupta  IN          185

Fake sharma IN          183

Manish Kumawat US       192
```

what query should I use for getting desired results

Comment: What exactly is the criteria you want to filter on if id is not good enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   user_profile_data.*
FROM     relation_table
    JOIN user_profile_data
      ON user_profile_data.ref_user_id = relation_table.user2
WHERE    relation_table.type  = 1
     AND relation_table.user1 = 184
     AND user_profile_data.full_name > (
       SELECT full_name
       FROM   user_profile_data
       WHERE  REF_USER_ID = 182
     )
ORDER BY user_profile_data.full_name
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340f0/3/0).

Comment: that solved the problem is there any mysql function built for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` as below:

```
      SELECT user_profile_data.*
      FROM relation_table,user_profile_data
      WHERE user_profile_data.ref_user_id=relation_table.user2
            and relation_table.type = 1 
            AND relation_table.user1 = 184
      ORDER BY user_profile_data.full_name ASC
      LIMIT 3,3
```

Comment: cannot use LIMIT as range of results required is not specified